# C# forms not loading through switch statement

Tags: c#, authentication, switch-statement

once insert user name and password, the relevant forms are not loading. only login screen getting hide/closed. user roles/passwords/ everythin is 100% correct. The output of the "role" is also correct.
Please advise.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable result = uc.Login(tbxUserName.Text, tbxPassword.Text);
        if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            string role = result.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();

            switch (role)
            {
                case "User":
                    FrmUser fuser = new FrmUser();
                    fuser.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;

                case "Admin":
                    FrmMain fmain = new FrmMain();
                    fmain.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Invalid User Name or Password", "Incorrect Login Details",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Did you check by placing the breakpoint near switch case and tested it?

Comment: Have you tried `fuser.Show()` instead of `fuser.ShowDialog()` ? ShowDialog will return modal form that restrict access to parent form until returning result(s): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried. same results. Once i insert the password everything disappear but visual studio is showing that application is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that rather than executing `this.Close()` to close login form on every role, keep that login form hidden behind after successful login:

```
if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();
        string role = result.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();

        switch (role)
        {
            case "User":
                FrmUser fuser = new FrmUser();
                fuser.ShowDialog();
                // note that this.Close() removed
                break;

            case "Admin":
                FrmMain fmain = new FrmMain();
                fmain.ShowDialog();
                // note that this.Close() removed
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Invalid User Name or Password", "Incorrect Login Details",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Application.Exit(); // optional, use if you want to exit all app window when wrong credentials supplied
    }
```

and place closing handler on both user & main form instead, thus closing one of them will also close hidden login form:

```
private void FrmUser_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     this.Close();
}

private void FrmMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     this.Close();
}
```

Reference: [When this.Close() executed all forms close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730831/when-this-close-executed-all-forms-close)

Hope your problem(s) solved, CMIIW.

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate. result is same. appreciate your time.

Comment: From this point, I still can't determine which form you've set as main form on Application.Run inside Main method. Assume if that login form becomes main form, closing it means terminate entire application. If that condition suits you, choose another form rather than login form to set as main form at first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is strange. Could You check if the Form is open and somehow has lost Focus? You can do that putting the following snippet after this statement:

```
fuser.ShowDialog();
```

Code to check if Form is still open:

```
if (Application.OpenForms[fuser.Name] == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form is not open");
}
```

Hope this may help.